# Applications not fully realising the resolution has changed

Tags: linux, resolution, xrandr

I'm running the i3 wm under Arch, and regularly switch screen resolutions because of different external displays and just using the laptop screen. I have these two shortcuts that I use for this:

```
bindsym $mod+F11 exec xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
bindsym $mod+F12 exec xrandr --auto
```

They work great and the app windows do correctly stretch to their tile size, but I notice that if an app is started during my smaller laptop resolution, then I switch to a larger one, some apps behave in a way that leads me to believe they still think they're on their "startup" resolution.

For example Chrome has a symptom of HTML5 desktop notifications being on the "bottom right" actually show in the middle of the screen, presumably because that position is the size of the laptop resolution. I can fix this by restarting Chrome.

Another app is IntelliJ IDEA, where dialog boxes and context menus always adhere to what seems like the smaller resolution. Restarting also helps.

Also I notice some apps do behave correctly, e.g. dunst and xscreensaver.

My question is am I doing something that isn't informing the new resolution to these apps correctly, or are these bugs specific to each individual app? Is fixing the bug or restarting the app the only way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in the application:

Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389171

Can not find a bug for IntelliJ. I will report soon.